# Prestashop 1.5 - Categories block

Tags: prestashop

I am new in using PrestaShop, my version is 1.5.6.0 and I would like to make the 'Categories block' module like  the 'Top horizontal menu' but a vertical flyout one, containing just the product categories, is that possible without me having to buy a specific module for this? I searched a lot, but couldn't find a solution.

If anyone had encountered such an issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue solved, I modified the 'Top horizontal menu' module and created a custom Left menu module that adds the needed functionality.